# Upgrade failed. Retry the upgrade after migrating your data to hashed storage

Tags: docker, gitlab-ce

i have the following docker imgage `gitlab/gitlab-ce` to make a local Gitlab server
and i have the following docker-compose file:

```
  git:
    container_name: git-server
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
    ports:
      - '8090:80'
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    networks:
      - net
```

when i do `docker-compose up` after a minute i get this error `Upgrade failed. Retry the upgrade after migrating your data to hashed storage.` and the container exited.
how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to migrate to `hashed storage` after the creation of the `Gitlab server container` and before creating any groups or projects in Gitlab.

Use the following command inside Gitlab server:

- Omnibus installation:

  `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:storage:migrate_to_hashed`
- Source installation:

  `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:storage:migrate_to_hashed RAILS_ENV=production`

Now you can find your groups and projects under `@hashed` folder.

For information on interpreting the relative path, see:
https://0xacab.org/help/administration/repository_storage_types.md#translate-hashed-storage-paths

Answer (score 0):

This error could appear also, when you have no connection to configured external postgresql database. Then check next section at your `gitlab.rb`:

```rb
# Fill in the values for database.yml
gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = 'postgresql'
gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = 'utf8'
gitlab_rails['db_host'] = '172.22.22.7'
gitlab_rails['db_port'] = '5432'
gitlab_rails['db_username'] = 'gitlab'
gitlab_rails['db_password'] = '***'
```